# Python 3.6 validating an integer input

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6 currently and my code currently is asking a user to input 2 integers and convert them into binary form, this is not a problem, the issue that I have is when it asks the user to input a number, if they put anything other than an integer, it will break the code and come up with an error, is there a specific few lines of code that will ensure that errors will not display if letters or floats are inputted?

```
def add():

    Num1 = int(input("Input the first number between 0 and 255, the calculated answer must not be above 255: "))
    Num2 = int(input("Input the second number between 0 and 255, the calculated answer must not be above 255: "))
```

I have tried one method which was:

```
if type(Num1) != int:
    print("Please input a number")
    add()
```

However I still get errors when testing the code.

I would like the code to detect that a string or float has been inputted, then reload the "def" function without giving a syntax error.

This is the print result:

[image: Print result]

Comment: Use exception handling to catch the error. Do you know how to use `try`?

Comment: I do not know how to use try, I have never used it in any of my Python codes before

Comment: Read up on using it. It's needed here, and is necessary knowledge for general programming anyway.

Comment: Technically there are other ways of solving it, but using try/catch is the most straightforward.

Comment: Oh, sure I will start to read up on it, thank you

Comment: Once you understand how it works, you just need to `catch` the `ValueError` that `int` throws.

Comment: I have updated my code now using ValueError

Comment: while True:
        try:
            Num1 = int(input("Please enter a number between 0 and 255, note that the final sum cannot be above 255: "))
            Num2 = int(input("Please enter a number betweem 0 and 255 note that the final sum cannot be above 255: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("ERROR Please input a decimal between 0 and 255.")

            continue
        else:

            break

Comment: This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the gist of how to get an integer from the command line. It works using a while loop and try/except statements. You can add the checks for the integer range. You can use this code to create a function, which can be called twice for your particular problem.

```
n = None
while True:
    n = input('enter an integer')
    try:
        n = int(n)
        break
    except:
        continue
```